# Grails findByName Regex

Tags: regex, grails, findby

I have a domain-class called `option`. There is an attribute called `name`.

The names are like:

```
abc.1
abc.2
xxx.1
xxx.2
xxx.3
```

I want all options that start with abc.
Normally I use Options.findByName("xyz")
But i want all that start with abc. So in that example:

```
abc.1
abc.2
```

The regex could be /abc(.).*/

But where I have to write that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need only simple "startsWith" condition, you can use like:

```
  Options.findAllByNameLike("abc%")
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using colusers inside the findAll /findByName method
Have u tried this one ?

`Example`

```
def result = ["abc1", "acb2", "abc3"].findAll { it ==~ /abc.*/ }
```

`or in your case`

```
def result = Options.findByName { it ==~ /abc.*/ }
```

Or refer this link for bunch of reference on regular expression http://groovy.codehaus.org/Regular+Expressions

Cheers!